# Cygwin Terminal GDB list function not working

Tags: c++, windows, gcc, gdb, cygwin

I recently downloaded cygwin terminal 32 bit with gdb, gcc, and g++. I wrote a simple c program and called it code.c. It goes as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int i;
  for(i = 0; i<10; i++)
  {
    printf("Hello, World!\n");
  }
}
```

First I opened cygwin terminal, navigated to the appropriate directory, and ran the command:

```
gcc code.c
```

This worked correctly and it created an executable called a.exe in the same directory.
I then loaded the executable's symbols into gdb and initialized gdb with the following command:

```
gdb -q ./a.exe
```

This also works correctly as it says: 
`Reading symbols from ./a.exe...done.`

Then I tested out some of gdb's functions.

`disassemble main` outputted the correct assembly instructions and `run` correctly ran the program.

However, when I tried `list` in order to output the c source code, I received no output and when I typed `list main` I received the following:

```
1        usr/src/debug/cygwin-2.3.1-1/winsup/cygwin/crt0.c: No such file or directory
```

My problem is that the list command was working previously and for some reason stopped working correctly. I'm thinking it may be a problem with my cygwin installation or maybe that I added c:\cygwin\bin to my windows Path variable manually. Any help or suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need `gcc -g code.c` to annotate debug info. Otherwise debugger cannot work.

Comment: Thanks that fixed it. I will accept your answer once Stack Overflow allows me to

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem you have to install from cygwin gcc-debuginfo or gdb-debuginfo or both